# Fuzzy matching issue with matching nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called `RawDatabase` which I am am snapping values to a validation list which is called `ValidationLists`. I take a specific column from the RawDatabase and compare the elements to the validation list.  The entry will be snapped to the entry in the validation list it most closely resembles.

The code looks like this:

```
def GetStandardisedField(rawDatabase,validationLists,field):
print('Standardising ', field,' ...')

my_list = validationLists[field]

l1=[]
    
for x in rawDatabase[field]:
    
    choice = process.extractOne(x, my_list)[0]
    l1.append(choice)
 
rawDatabase['choice']=l1
rawDatabase[field] = rawDatabase['choice']
del rawDatabase['choice']

return rawDatabase
```

In an example the rawDatabase[field] looks like:

```
0       yes
1    YES123
2     nO023
3         n
4       NaN
```

and the validationList looks like:

```
YES
NO
```

I am trying to snap all the values so that the new rawDatabase[field] looks like:

```
0       YES
1       YES
2        NO
3        NO
4
```

I however seem to have a problem when I try to snap an `NaN` value to the `validationList` (even when I include `NaN` in the `validationList` as a test).

What is the best way to handle NaN values (so the NaN value in the snapped dataset is blank)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
l=['YES',"NO"]
a=[]
for x in df.Col1:
    try:
        a.append([process.extract(x, l, limit=1)][0][0][0])
    except:
        a.append(np.nan)

df['target']=a
df
Out[1261]: 
     Col1 target
0     yes    YES
1  YES123    YES
2   nO023     NO
3       n     NO
4     NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I like python's [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) for this type of thing.

You can get string matches with `get_close_matches`

```
from difflib import get_close_matches
foo = pd.Series(('yes', 'YES123', 'nO023', 'nO023', 'n', np.nan))
validation_list = ['YES', 'NO']

def get_matches(x):
    if pd.isnull(x):
        return np.nan
    else:
        return get_close_matches(str(x).upper(), validation_list, 1, 0.2)[0]

foo.apply(get_matches)

0    YES
1    YES
2     NO
3     NO
4    NaN
```

`get_close_matches` takes the value you wish to test, a list to test against, the number of matches to return and the threshold for how similar a match needs to be in order to return it. The return type is a list, so just take the 0th item in that list